# Why Fasttext train_unsupervised freezing after training for hours?

Tags: python-3.x, word-embedding, fasttext

I have 0.9 Million text files in a folder "raw_data" each containing Bangla language text(Unicode characters). I am training a fasttext model with the following self explanatory code

```
def ft_train(dimensions, n_epoch, min_count=0, threads=4):
  tic = time.time()
  for root, _, files in os.walk("/home/Akib/Raw_data/raw_data", topdown=False):
    for f in files:
        try:
          fpath = os.path.join(root, f)
          model = fasttext.train_unsupervised(fpath, dim = dimensions, epoch=n_epoch, minCount= min_count, thread= threads)
        except:
          pass
  toc = time.time()
  print(str((toc - tic)/60), " min")
  return model
```

It trained for 2 days showing progress like as follows

```
272198.txt
Read 0M words
Number of words:  18
Number of labels: 0
Progress: 100.0% words/sec/thread:    1541 lr:  0.000000 loss:  4.155107 ETA:   0h 0m

40132.txt
Read 0M words
Number of words:  114
Number of labels: 0
Progress: 100.0% words/sec/thread:   10125 lr:  0.000000 loss:  4.120082 ETA:   0h 0m
```

But after 2 days of training it freezes without any error just showing that the intended file has 1 word. But it actually has more than 40 words.

[image]

I have checked for RAM and disk space availability but it seems that's not the issue as I have enough space available both in RAM and memory. I don't understand if it's an issue with my code.

Comment: To my knowledge, you are training 900K models, not one, and your LR is zero. I suggest looking into that. Maybe the RAM is full? you can try `import gc; gc.enable(); gc.collect()`

Comment: Thanks for locating the probable causes. 
But he problem in my case was, some of the files literally had 1 word in them. but fasttext expects minimum 5 words in a file if I remember correctly. So, after ignoring those files with lesser words, the training ran fine.